# Personal Hotspot not forwarding DNS requests to the interent on iPhone 7 with IOS 11

Tags: dns, tethering, ios

I have been using my iPhone 7 plus as a personal hotspot since I bought it.  The hotspot worked fine with IOS 10.  After upgrading my iPhone to IOS 11, the personal hotspot now exhibits the following behavior: It lets one or more devices connect to the personal hotspot but will not forward DNS requests to the internet.  All web pages show "unable to connect".  If I had a browser open to web pages prior to connecting the computer to the iPhone's hotspot, those webpages can still be browsed because the system cached the IP address of the site's domain.

This happens regardless whether I connect via wireless, Bluetooth, or USB.   If I turn off the personal hotspot and turn it back on, all devices easily reconnect, but the behavior repeats: no DNS requests go through.  It does not matter whether the tethered device is a laptop, tablet or IOT device.  The behavior is the same.

I've done all of the usual folk-remedy "fixes" like restarting the phone, resetting network settings, recreating the hotspot name & password, and so forth with no change.  I've hard-coded google's DNS servers into the DNS settings of the IP4 and IP6 network settings into the laptop with no success.

Any point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please confirm that this is definitely a DNS issue?  Let's have you go to http://172.217.3.196/ (one of Google's IPs), then tether and reload the page and put in a search, and see if that works.  If it does, we can safely assume it is a DNS issue, in which case we can proceed to running a traceroute and seeing if it might be a port-blocking issue.

Comment: @Harv. Of course, as I try, tethering starts to behave.  It's done this (behave) once before and was then followed a long drought of malfunction.   When it starts to misbehave again - and it will - I'll perform that test and leave another comment.  Thanks in advance for being patient.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with my Android phone, the working fix that I googled up was to edit manually APN settings and assure that "APN type" for APN used for data traffic reads "default,supl,dun". (It had been "default,supl")